# Strategy.exit() & Strategy.close(): how many of them?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Curious enough... I wish to know how many trades have been closed by `strategy.exit()` conditions `(profit=n, stop=x)` and how many have been closed by `strategy.close()` which is triggered by other events of my strategy.
I need this to better calculate the average fees, giventhe fact that all strategy.exit() trades are **limit** orders, while strategy.close() are **market** ones.
Any ideas how to determine it?

Original code is something like this:

```
switch
enterLong() =>
    if strategy.position_size <= 0
        alert(closeShort_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(new2_enterLong_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        strategy.close("SELL", comment="Reverse Position")
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "BUY", profit=offsetLongTP)
        
enterShort() =>
    if strategy.position_size >= 0
        alert(closeLong_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(new2_enterShort_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        strategy.close("BUY", comment="Reverse Position")
        strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)                          
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "SELL", profit=offsetShortTP)

exitShortSL() =>
    if strategy.position_size <= 0
        alert(closeShort_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(new2_enterLong_SL_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        strategy.close("SELL", comment='STOPLOSS Short')
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "BUY", profit=SL_offsetLongTP, loss=SL_offsetLongSL)
    
exitLongSL() =>
    if strategy.position_size >= 0
        alert(closeLong_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        alert(new2_enterShort_SL_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
        strategy.close("BUY", comment='STOPLOSS Long')
        strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "SELL", profit=SL_offsetShortTP, loss=SL_offsetShortSL)

exitLongNarrow() =>
    alert(closeLong_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    strategy.close("BUY", comment="Flat market exit")

exitShortNarrow() =>
    alert(closeShort_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    strategy.close("SELL", comment="Flat market exit")
```